Python error when installing Stable Diffusion
I was recently trying to install StableDiffusion natively on my SSD that is not my main C drive, everything was working until I tried running webui-user.bat and it said "Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully."

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.command.test'

This is my output:
venv "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version: v1.10.1
Commit hash: 82a973c04367123ae98bd9abdf80d9eda9b910e2
Installing requirements
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 39, in main
    prepare_environment()
  File "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 423, in prepare_environment
    run_pip(f"install -r \"{requirements_file}\"", "requirements")
  File "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 144, in run_pip
    return run(f'"{python}" -m pip {command} --prefer-binary{index_url_line}', desc=f"Installing {desc}", errdesc=f"Couldn't install {desc}", live=live)
  File "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 116, in run
    raise RuntimeError("\n".join(error_bits))
RuntimeError: Couldn't install requirements.
Command: "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install -r "requirements_versions.txt" --prefer-binary
Error code: 1
stdout: Collecting setuptools==69.5.1 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 1))
  Using cached setuptools-69.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
Collecting GitPython==3.1.32 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 2))
  Using cached GitPython-3.1.32-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10.0 kB)
Collecting Pillow==9.5.0 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 3))
  Using cached Pillow-9.5.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (9.7 kB)
Collecting accelerate==0.21.0 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 4))
  Using cached accelerate-0.21.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (17 kB)
Collecting blendmodes==2022 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 5))
  Using cached blendmodes-2022-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting clean-fid==0.1.35 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 6))
  Using cached clean_fid-0.1.35-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (36 kB)
Collecting diskcache==5.6.3 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 7))
  Using cached diskcache-5.6.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Collecting einops==0.4.1 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 8))
  Using cached einops-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting facexlib==0.3.0 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 9))
  Using cached facexlib-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting fastapi==0.94.0 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 10))
  Using cached fastapi-0.94.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (25 kB)
Collecting gradio==3.41.2 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 11))
  Using cached gradio-3.41.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (17 kB)
Collecting httpcore==0.15 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 12))
  Using cached httpcore-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Collecting inflection==0.5.1 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 13))
  Using cached inflection-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting jsonmerge==1.8.0 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 14))
  Using cached jsonmerge-1.8.0.tar.gz (26 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting kornia==0.6.7 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 15))
  Using cached kornia-0.6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting lark==1.1.2 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 16))
  Using cached lark-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.26.2 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 17))
  Using cached numpy-1.26.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
Collecting omegaconf==2.2.3 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 18))
  Using cached omegaconf-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting open-clip-torch==2.20.0 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 19))
  Using cached open_clip_torch-2.20.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (46 kB)
Collecting piexif==1.1.3 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 20))
  Using cached piexif-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf==3.20.0 in m:\ai\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 21)) (3.20.0)
Collecting psutil==5.9.5 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 22))
  Using cached psutil-5.9.5-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (21 kB)
Collecting pytorch_lightning==1.9.4 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 23))
  Using cached pytorch_lightning-1.9.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Collecting resize-right==0.0.2 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 24))
  Using cached resize_right-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (551 bytes)
Collecting safetensors==0.4.2 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 25))
  Using cached safetensors-0.4.2-cp310-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting scikit-image==0.21.0 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 26))
  Using cached scikit_image-0.21.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Collecting spandrel==0.3.4 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 27))
  Using cached spandrel-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Collecting spandrel-extra-arches==0.1.1 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 28))
  Using cached spandrel_extra_arches-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting tomesd==0.1.3 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 29))
  Using cached tomesd-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in m:\ai\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 30)) (2.1.2+cu121)
Collecting torchdiffeq==0.2.3 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 31))
  Using cached torchdiffeq-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (488 bytes)
Collecting torchsde==0.2.6 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 32))
  Using cached torchsde-0.2.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
Collecting transformers==4.30.2 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 33))
  Using cached transformers-4.30.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (113 kB)
Collecting httpx==0.24.1 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 34))
  Using cached httpx-0.24.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.4 kB)
Collecting pillow-avif-plugin==1.4.3 (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 35))
  Using cached pillow_avif_plugin-1.4.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting gitdb<5,>=4.0.1 (from GitPython==3.1.32->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 2))
  Using cached gitdb-4.0.11-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in m:\ai\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from accelerate==0.21.0->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 4)) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in m:\ai\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from accelerate==0.21.0->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 4)) (6.0.1)
Collecting aenum<4,>=3.1.7 (from blendmodes==2022->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 5))
  Using cached aenum-3.1.15-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Collecting deprecation<3,>=2.1.0 (from blendmodes==2022->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 5))
  Using cached deprecation-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in m:\ai\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from clean-fid==0.1.35->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 6)) (0.16.2+cu121)
Collecting scipy>=1.0.1 (from clean-fid==0.1.35->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 6))
  Using cached scipy-1.14.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.28.1 in m:\ai\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from clean-fid==0.1.35->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 6)) (4.66.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in m:\ai\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from clean-fid==0.1.35->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 6)) (2.32.3)
Collecting filterpy (from facexlib==0.3.0->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 9))
  Using cached filterpy-1.4.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numba (from facexlib==0.3.0->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 9))
  Using cached numba-0.60.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Collecting opencv-python (from facexlib==0.3.0->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 9))
  Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.84-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Collecting pydantic!=1.7,!=1.7.1,!=1.7.2,!=1.7.3,!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<2.0.0,>=1.6.2 (from fastapi==0.94.0->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 10))
  Using cached pydantic-1.10.17-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (153 kB)
Collecting starlette<0.27.0,>=0.26.0 (from fastapi==0.94.0->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 10))
  Using cached starlette-0.26.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting aiofiles<24.0,>=22.0 (from gradio==3.41.2->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 11))
  Using cached aiofiles-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.7 kB)
Collecting altair<6.0,>=4.2.0 (from gradio==3.41.2->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 11))
  Using cached altair-5.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.2 kB)
Collecting ffmpy (from gradio==3.41.2->-r requirements_versions.txt (line 11))
  Using cached ffmpy-0.3.2.tar.gz (5.5 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

stderr:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [17 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "M:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dkhegr9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
    File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dkhegr9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dkhegr9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 497, in run_setup
      super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dkhegr9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.command.test'
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

I tried installing setuptools from here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/releases/tag/v72.0.0, but it did not work.
I then tried installing setuptools v69.5.1 because that was claimed to be the version that works better with Stable Diffusion, but it gives the same error.

This looks like a bug in setuptools v72: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4519

Same error encountered using "pip install spyder"  on a venv python 3.12.4 installation with setuptools(72.0.0) on ubuntu 22.04.

Yes, setuptools just had 72.0.0 today and it has removed "test" command from code.
If you are using pip to install packages, the workaround is to install setuptools==71.1.0 and use "--no-build-isolation" argument.
example:

pip install setuptools==71.1.0
pip install <your application/package> --no-build-isolation

